# Haskell Happy parser not going further

Tags: parsing, haskell, happy

I'm implementing a parser for a language similar to Oberon.
I've successfully written the lexer using Alex since I can see that the list of tokens returned by the lexer is correct.

When I give the tokens list to the parser, it stops at the first token.

This is my parser:

```
...

%name myParse
%error { parseError }

%token
    KW_PROCEDURE        { KW_TokenProcedure }
    KW_END              { KW_TokenEnd }
    ';'                 { KW_TokenSemiColon }
    identifier          { TokenVariableIdentifier $$ }

%%

ProcedureDeclaration    :   ProcedureHeading ';' ProcedureBody identifier     { putStrLn("C") }

ProcedureHeading        :   KW_PROCEDURE identifier { putStrLn("D") }

ProcedureBody           :   KW_END                      { putStrLn("E") }   
                        | DeclarationSequence KW_END    { putStrLn("F") }

DeclarationSequence     :   ProcedureDeclaration        { putStrLn("G") }

{
parseError :: [Token] -> a
parseError _ = error "Parse error"

main = do
  inStr <- getContents
  print (alexScanTokens inStr)
  myParse (alexScanTokens inStr)
  putStrLn("DONE")
}
```

This is the test code I give to the parser:

```
PROCEDURE proc;
END proc
```

This is the token list returned by the lexer:

```
[KW_TokenProcedure,TokenVariableIdentifier "proc",KW_TokenSemiColon,KW_TokenEnd,TokenVariableIdentifier "proc"]
```

The parser does't give any error, but it sticks to my ProcedureDeclaration rule, printing only C.

This is what the output looks like:

```
C
DONE
```

Any idea why?

---

UPDATE:

I've made a first step forward and I was able to parse the test input given before. Now I changed my parser to recognize the declaration of multiple procedures on the same level. To do this, this is how my new parse looks like:

```
...

%name myParse
%error { parseError }

%token
    KW_PROCEDURE        { KW_TokenProcedure }
    KW_END              { KW_TokenEnd }
    ';'                 { KW_TokenSemiColon }
    identifier          { TokenVariableIdentifier $$ }

%%

ProcedureDeclarationList    :   ProcedureDeclaration                                { $1 }
                            |   ProcedureDeclaration ';' ProcedureDeclarationList   { $3:[$1] }

ProcedureDeclaration        :   ProcedureHeading ';' ProcedureBody identifier       { addProcedureToProcedure $1 $3 }

ProcedureHeading            :   KW_PROCEDURE identifier                             { defaultProcedure { procedureName = $2 } }

ProcedureBody               :   KW_END                                              { Nothing }
                            |   DeclarationSequence KW_END                          { Just $1 }

DeclarationSequence         :    ProcedureDeclarationList                           { $1 }

{
parseError :: [Token] -> a
parseError _ = error "Parse error"

main = do
  inStr <- getContents
  let result = myParse (alexScanTokens inStr)
  putStrLn ("result: " ++ show(result))
}
```

The thing is, it fails to compile giving me this error:

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t5 ~ [t5]
    Expected type: HappyAbsSyn t5 t5 t6 t7 t8 t9
                   -> HappyAbsSyn t5 t5 t6 t7 t8 t9
                   -> HappyAbsSyn t5 t5 t6 t7 t8 t9
                   -> HappyAbsSyn t5 t5 t6 t7 t8 t9
      Actual type: HappyAbsSyn t5 t5 t6 t7 t8 t9
                   -> HappyAbsSyn t5 t5 t6 t7 t8 t9
                   -> HappyAbsSyn t5 t5 t6 t7 t8 t9
                   -> HappyAbsSyn [t5] t5 t6 t7 t8 t9
    ...
```

I know for sure that it's caused by the second element of my `ProcedureDeclarationsList` rule, but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things to note here.

1. happy uses the first production rule as the top-level production for `myParse`.

Your first production rule is `ProcedureDeclaration`, so that's all it's going to try to parse. You probably want to make `DeclarationSequence` the first rule.

2. The return type of your productions are IO-actions, and in Haskell IO-actions are values. They are not "executed" until they become part of `main`. That means you need to write your productions like this:

   ```
   DeclarationSequence : ProcedureDeclaration
       { do $1; putStrLn("G") }
   ProcedureDeclaration : ProcedureHeading ';' ProcedureBody identifier
       { do $1; $3; putStrLn("C") }
   ```

That is, the return value of the `DeclarationSequence` rule is the IO-action returned by `ProcedureDeclaration` followed by `putStrLn "G"`.

And the return value of the `ProducedureDeclaration` rule is the action returned by `ProcudureHeading` followed by the action returned by `ProcedureBody` followed by `putStrLn "C"`.

You could also write the RHS of the rules using the `>>` operator:

```
{ $1 >> putStrLn "G" }
{ $1 >> $3 >> putStrLn "C" }
```

Note that you have to decide the order in which to sequence the actions - i.e. pre-/post-/in- order.

Working example: http://lpaste.net/162432

Comment: I was able to make the parser working but then, adding the possibility to define multiple procedures at the same level, I get an error compiling. I've updated the question to show this problem.

Comment: It's really a completely different question now. Please open up a new SO question for it.

Comment: Also, when you create the new question, please include a compilable example. We're going to need to know the definitions of the functions like `defaultProcedure` and `addProcedureToProcedure`, etc.

Comment: Ok, so now I'll open a new question putting all the info needed. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems okay your expression has been parsed just fine. Check the return type of `myParse`, I guess it will be `IO ()`, and the actual action will be `putStrLn("D")` - is what your wrote in `ProcedureDeclaration`. Next, your put call to `myParse` in the do block, it will be interpreted as `print .. >> myParse (..) >> putStrLn ..` or just linking monadic actions. `myParse` will return an action which will print "D" so the output is exactly what one would expect.

You have other actions defined in `ProcedureBody` and `DeclarationSequence`. But you never use these actions in any way, it's like you will write:

```
    do
      let a = putStrLn "E"
      putStrLn("C")
```

Which will output "C", `a` is not used by any means. Same with your parser. If you want to invoke these actions, try to write `$1 >> putStrLn("C") >> $2` in `ProcedureDeclaration` associated code.